# Upgraded C++ Project to VS2015, but the Linker is still looking for VC100 Boost library

Tags: c++, visual-studio, boost

I have upgraded my C++ project from VS2008 to VS2015.
The `Platform Toolset` is set to `Visual Studio 2015 (v140)`. If it matters, the `Target Platform Version` is set to `8.1`.

I built boost using `toolset=msvc-14.0` and put the built libraries into the place my project is expecting them.

When I build my project, I get a linker error:

```
LNK1104 cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc100-mt-1_43.lib'
```

Why is it looking for the `vc100` library and not the `vc140` one?

---

1. It's the first project out of 2 that is failing.
2. In the `.vcproj` file there is no reference that I can see to `vc100`.

Comment: Have you fully rebuilt your project? Have you opened the project files in a text editor to make sure there aren't any leftovers after conversion which would point to vc100?

Comment: What version of boost are you using? Does it know about VS 2015?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linking to boost libraries on Windows is done automatically through auto linking and `#pragma` directives. The version number it looks to link against is defined in boost\config\auto_link.hpp where it goes through a bunch of `#if` and `#elif`s on your `MSVC` version and if the version is higher than any of the ones it knows about then it just sets the version number to the highest one it knows about. For boost 1.57 that is vc140, for your version of boost that is presumably vc100.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this. Do you know whether I should run into any issues upgrading boost to 1.57?

Comment: @Coxy Depends upon which boost libraries you are using. There is such a huge selection of libraries available in Boost of varying levels of quality and stability. I've seen that upgrading Boost serialization can be a pain. Generally it is better to upgrade fairly frequently and incrementally rather than make huge break the world upgrades twice a decade.

Comment: I've edited auto_link.hpp, but it looks like thread and wave won't build under vs140. I'll try 1.57.

Comment: This is probably one of the most important boost-related answers out there right now :P Well, at least for me xD You have no idea how many files I poured over until I came to a similar conclusion after doing a battery of search-in-file checks across our codebase....